# 'checked' is null or not an object - only IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

This problem exists only in IE browser, in mozilla its working fine... i have to delete a row on click on checkbox.... 
Here is my code :

```
<table width="100%" id="seller">
<tr id="row_1" class="row">
 <td><input type="checkbox" name="delete_seller" id="delete_seller" value="1" /></td>
</tr>
<tr id="row_2" class="row">
 <td><input type="checkbox" name="delete_seller" id="delete_seller" value="2" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="button" id="delete" name="delete" value="Delete" onclick="delete_row('seller')"/>
```

---

```
    var delete_ids = [];
    function delete_row(tableID){
      var rows = document.getElementsByClassName('row');
      var delItems = document.getElementsByName('delete_seller');

      for(var i=0;i < rows.length;i++){
        if(delItems[i].checked == true){
          delete_ids.push(rows[i].id);
          jQuery(rows[i]).remove();
          i = i-1;
        }
      }
}
```

Showing error on page : **'checked' is null or not an object**. 
can one please tell me the fix .

thanks in advance,
sri..

Comment: What's the `tableID` parameter for?

Comment: yeah, not using any where tableId. need to remove . thanks

Comment: `getElementsByClassname` isn't implemented in IE. http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2008/05/getelementsbycl.html

Comment: ID's should be unique.  `delete_seller` should be a classname.

Comment: i was getting values in delete_ids array. I'm thiking the issue is with the lines jQuery(rows[i]).remove(); and i = i-1;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace the loop with jQuery, like this:

```
delete_ids.push.apply(delete_ids,
    $('tr.row:has(.delete:checked)').remove()
        .map(funcion() { return this.id; })
);
```

This will select all `tr.row` element that `:has` a `.delete` element that is `:checked`.
It calls `.remove()` to remove the rows, then calls `.map()` to get the rows' IDs, and applies the `push` function to add them to your array.

You can avoid the `push.apply` by changing it to

```
    $('tr.row:has(.delete:checked)').remove()
        .each(funcion() { delete_ids.push(this.id); });
```

**EDIT**: Try this:

```
    $('tr.row:has(.delete_seller:checked)')
        .each(funcion() { delete_ids.push(this.id); })
        .remove();
```

Comment: +1 Second time you beat me today. Please do add some more explanatory text though.

Comment: My bad , I edited my post , please go through...This is what i'm using. thanks

Comment: @Srinath: Change `.delete` to match your checkboxes.

Comment: Hi SLaks,
I changed to .delete_seller. but id name is common for all rows. i was displaying the list using loop  . should i get all using var delItems = document.getElementsByName('delete_seller'); and use delItems ?

Comment: @Slaks, Could you please provide me full solution from my code . i was running under issues. this was ragging me since 1 day. 

thanks .

Comment: @Srinath: Try my edit.  If you have issues, please describe them.

Comment: var delete_ids = [];
    function delete_row(tableID){
      var rows = document.getElementsByClassName('row');
      var delItems = document.getElementsByName('delete_seller');
      
     jQuery('tr.row:has(.delete_seller:checked)').remove()
            .each(function() { delete_ids.push(this.id); });

this is how i am using.please tell me if i'm doing wrong

Comment: @Srinath: `getElementsByClassName` doesn't exist in IE.  Remove `var rows` and `var delItems`.

Comment: @Slaks , yeah this works great in IE . I added setAttribute("className") and works good. thanks Slaks

Comment: @Srinath: Then you should accept this answer by clicking the hollow check.

Answer (score 0):

Both your checkboxes and your button are called "delete" and your `delItems` variable will contain the button as well. The button doesn't have a checked attribute, which I'm guessing is where IE complains about it.

Although in the example you give there are fewer elements with class 'row' than there are elements with name 'delete' which should mean you don't get to the point in the loop where delItems[i] refers to the button. Unless there are more elements class 'row' on the page.

Comment: My bad , I edited my post , please go through...This is what i'm using. thanks